# jquery, get url segment - ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Say I have a list of items from a database. Next to each item there is a delete link. the links look something like: http://example.com/exp/delete/1 - 1 is the ID of the record I want to delete. How can I grab the ID to pass through AJAX?

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for a regex to grab whatever comes after the last slash?

Comment: This would work... I'm really bad with regex and js!

Comment: figured it out: $(this).attr("href").match(/[^/]*$/i);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure it out!

```
$(this).attr("href").match(/[^/]*$/i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to some string parsing.  Find the index of the last / and then get a substring from that index to the end of the string.  You'll be left with the id you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [Purl](https://github.com/allmarkedup/purl). It's a great plugin and it doesn't have jQuery dependency.

Since this question has a top spot on Google, I thought I'd throw my hat in the ring on an old question.